Username as Tax_Query Term
I'm hoping someone may be able to point me in the direction of where i've gone wrong. I have a page which has a shortcode to pull through Referrals for the currently logged in user.
It just needs to pull from a Custom Post Type (CPT) to show the correct posts that have been tagged from the custom taxonomy referral_members with the user_login. My Gravity Forms form is pushing the content correctly, and I can see the posts within the CPT in the backend. But when I try my code below it 500 server errors. I'm sure i've just done something wrong my end.
function your_referrals() {
global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();
$user_login = $current_user->user_login;
ob_start();
?>

<div class="referralsloop container">
<div class="referrals">
        <?php 
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'referrals',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'referral_members',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    =>  $user_login,
                'operator'  => 'IN',
                ),
            ),
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {   
        ?>
        <div class="referral">
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {  ?>
            <p><?php the_content();?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, you have no referrals yet.' ); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php $output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
} 
add_shortcode('your_referrals_shortcode', 'your_referrals');

Anyone any ideas why this is erroring. I'm sure that it will be something in my args that has done it.
Thanks in advance :)

have you checked your PHP error log? a 500 error is Nginx/Apache telling you something went wrong, the PHP error log contains the actual message and line number it happened on

as an aside 'posts_per_page' => '-1', should be 'posts_per_page' => -1,, but this still leaves you open to a problem where there are more posts than your server is capable of retrieving, it would be better to set this to a very high number you never expect to reach but know that your server can handle without hitting memory/time limits. The first 3 lines can be replaced with $current_user = wp_get_current_user();, and there should be checks for if the user is actually logged in. The post loop is also missing a call to the_post so when you call the_content it will always be the same

That was it... thank you :) I knew I'd screwed up somewhere.

hmm that wouldn't have generated a HTTP 500 or fatal errors

Forgot to add the final working code...
I needed to swap out the wp_get_current_user(); section at the start and I was missing the_post() part of the loop. Also the number of posts needed to be out of the '' marks.
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
ob_start();
?>

<div class="referralsloop container">
<div class="referrals">
        <?php 
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'referrals',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'referral_members',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    =>  $current_user->user_login,
                'operator'  => 'IN',
                ),
            ),
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {   
        ?>
        <div class="referral">
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <h4>Referral from <?php the_author();?></h4>
            <h6>Referral Date: <?php the_date();?></h6>
            <p><strong>Referral Priority:</strong> <?php the_field('priority');?><br/>
            <strong>Referral Contact Name:</strong> <?php the_field('referral_contact_name');?><br/>
            <strong>Referral Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:<?php the_field('referral_contact_email_address');?>"><?php the_field('referral_contact_email_address');?></a><br/>
            <strong>Referral Information</strong><br><?php the_field('referral_information');?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, you have no referrals yet.' ); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php $output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
} 
add_shortcode('your_referrals_shortcode', 'your_referrals');```



Solved it: I had missed out the the_post() part of the loop. Thanks everyone. :)
